# Плагин галереи на Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, изображения, fancybox, gallery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, плагин для галереи изображений на Vue.js, по аналогии с fancybox. Обязательно нужно, чтобы была возможность менять фото по колесу мыши. В fancybox как раз такой функционал есть, но аналога на Vue не могу найти

Answer (score 0):

Есть прекрасный аналог - [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/).
У него очень обширное API, а так же есть [компонент для vue.js](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper)

Очень удобный в использовании, так же есть возможность кастомизации и добавления своего функционала.